# Не работают тесты и gopath, как исправить?

Tags: golang

Подтягивает пути при импорте установленных библиотек
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при импорте пишет ошибку что не найдено именно в каталоге с Go
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

gopath прописан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему не подтягивает? не могу разобраться.

Еще почему-то не работают тесты, при нажатии на имени метода alt+enter не предлагает ничего, вроде должно предложить создать тест. Если создать файл руками, при запуске ругается, находил что нужно поставить галочку, но не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что пишет при запуске теста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

вы включили интеграцию с Go modules, но у вас нет go.mod фала

выполните команду `go mod init` в корневой директории. Эта команда создаст go.mod файл в корневой директории. Добавьте изменения по желанию.

Следующая команда - `go mod tidy` - обновит ваши внешние зависимости, на которые ссылаетесь в проекте и добавит в go.mod. также создаст go.sum

дальше - `go mod download` - выкачает указанные зависимости из go.mod с нужными версиями.

проверяем `go test -v ./...` - запустит ваши тесты(если на них не навешены тэни `// +build`)

дальше уже пробуйте запустить из IDE